# pytest-bdd Retrieve entire unique row based on particular value of outline table

Tags: python, pytest, python-behave, pytest-bdd

I am looking to get the entire unique row based on test_type_to_run value, for example I want to only retrieve the rows having test_type_to_run==regression and skip the rows with 'smoke'

```
Feature: Add a new module using API

Scenario Outline: the admin can Add a project
  Given need to call api with <type> for "createNewModule" and <apipayload> value and <test_type_to_run>
  Given set header "Content-Type:application/json" with <role>
  Given create payload as <apipayload>
  When Call "createNewModule" api using "POST" method
  Then validate the status code as <respcode> in response body
  Then validate the message is returned as <message>
  Then validate the DB records if the <message> is Success

}
```

```
Examples:
  |type   |apipayload         |respcode|msg    |role|test_type_to_run |
  |ValidValues|ValidValsAPI   |200     |Success|Tester|smoke|
  |InValidVals |InValidValsAPI|400     |Error|Tester|smoke|
  |ValidNumbers|ValidNumbersAPI|200     |Success|Developer|regression|
  |ValidIntegers|ValidIntegersAPI|202     |Success|Developer Admin|regression|
  |GarbageData|GarbageDataAPI|400     |Error|Developer Admin|regression|
```

Expected Test method:

```
@given(parsers.parse('need to call api with {type} for "{api}" and {api_payload} value and {test_type_to_run} with role {role}'))
 def need_to_call_api_for(api, test_type, api_payload, test_type_to_run):
   if test_type_to_run == "regression":
     site_url = call_api(api, payload=api_payload, test_type=type, role=role)
```

The above function should only have below input based on **test_type_to_run=="smoke"**:

```
|ValidValues|ValidValsAPI   |200     |Success|Tester|smoke|
|InValidVals |InValidValsAPI|400     |Error|Tester|smoke|
```

Can something like this be possbible in pytest-bdd ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use tags in your feature file, then use the tags in your conditional statement? If yes, you can get the tag from one of the [pytest-bdd hooks](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#hooks) and store to context or some variable and use as desired.

```
  @regression
  Scenario: Clicking a Button
    Given the user is on the website
  @smoke
  Scenario: Clicking a Button
    Given the user is on the website
```